# Can't Connect MYSQL server to VScode & General SQL installation issues

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-code

How do I install MySQL Workbench properly? Can't connect to the SQLTools extension in VSCode.I'm new to the database scene, and can't seem to grasp how to create a successful SQL server that I can use to manipulate data. But nothing I'm doing seems to work.

Should I use Gitbash to access the terminal? I tried using my password to make a new query but it wouldn't work on the workbench. I don't know how to start the SQL server in addition to not knowing how to properly change the profile for the Workbench from a previous account. A new developer, such as myself, would appreciate any insight!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

So that's really simple just install the mysql community server installer using this link https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Make sure to select the server only in the setup during installation if you are going to be using VS code as the client to manipulate sql queries

Then once that is done copy the bin path location from the mysql file directory (which is usually in the program files on your \C: drive on your computer) to the environment variables on your computer so that you can access mysql from the command line

Once that is done you can initialise a database from the normal command line but first type mysql -u root -p to start mysql in the command line

Then download the sql tools extension on vs code and create the database that wish